# Xlib and XCB. Multiple windows in one process. Xlib fails whereas XCB do not

Tags: linux, x11, xlib, window-managers, xcb

Not so long ago, I was faced with a fact that programming with `Xlib` in the presence of multiple threads and multiple windows is a thorny path. The problem I was faced with is that, that `Xlib`(or window manager) is forcefully closes a connection to the server after so called "top level" window is closed.

The problem is easy to reproduce, you just need to create a window, then close it. Try to use use a `Display` after the above steps. The fatal error will raise and program will exit. This is a strange behaviour of `Xlib`.

The problem were faced in several `SO` topics: [How do I gracefully exit an X11 event loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10792361/8339821), [How do you exit X11 program without Error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8176493/8339821). To summarize the discussions, It is noted somewhere in Xlib documentation that windows manager will close the connection.

Out of curiosity I checked `XCB` library for such behaviour. The `XCB`, compared to Xlib, behaved "normally" and I was able to create and destroy several windows with connection still in place.

The question is. How does `XCB` library performs in the presence of multiple windows and threads, so it does not show the `Xlib` faulty behaviour? Does the `XCB` uses `Xlib` under the hood, or does it sends commands to the X server in some other format? Excuse me, I am not so familiar, how to communicate to X11 protocol. And in particular, how it come, that window manager does not close the connection with `XCB`?

I will accept any answer that will shred a light on the matters. Will it be web-links to `XCB` source code, that explains the smart way of doing things. Or will it be explanation in terms of `X11` protocol. Or anything else.

Thanks for the long reading. I hope I did not tire you with all this text.

***Update***

***I've messed things up.*** The Xlib behaves as I expect, if WM_DELETE_WINDOW is set in WM_PROTOCOLS. It is just the ordering, or syncing, caused the connection to be in wrong state. I think that multiple threads have interfered with `Xlib` state in a random way and the event loop got wrong. I must warn others about Xlib, that a syncing should be made by means of variables or atomic primitives. The `Xlib` actual state change should be made only in the main thread and ***after the event loop had passed***.

Comment: The missing bit to not have the WM kill your X11 connection is a WM_PROTOCOLS property containing WM_DELETE_WINDOW. See ICCCM §4.1.2.7 and §4.2.8.1: https://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/sec-4.html#s-4.1.2.7 / https://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/sec-4.html#s-4.2.8.1

Comment: @UliSchlachter Your comment is the excat thing why I had posted the above two links. As it is written above: I had all the preparations, I do receive a clent message. Then WM closes the connection. That is it.

Comment: @UliSchlachter I forgot to mention that I do `DestoryWindow` after the client message. This was mentioned in the documentation as a valid procedure.

Comment: @UliSchlachter Ok, now I am confused. I've changed the order of my function calls a little, and the connection is here to stay. The programming is a magic art, sometimes. Need to investigate on that. Maybe the multiple threads gave me the wrong behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

> To summarize the discussions, It is noted somewhere in Xlib documentation that windows manager will close the connection.

With "somewhere" being the Xlib documentation.  And you should read those discussions more carefully, because you seem to have overlooked some important points.

> How does XCB library performs in the presence of multiple windows and
> threads, so it does not show the Xlib faulty behaviour?

You may not like Xlib's behavior in this area, but it is not "faulty".  It is documented, and it is useful for many programs.  Moreover, although closing the connection is the default behavior under Xlib when a top-level window is closed, it is not the only possible behavior.  Among the answers to the questions you linked, there is a description (and documentation citation) describing the relatively simple thing you need to do to avoid the X connection being closed when a top-level window is closed via its close button.

Considering, then, that we're talking about a *default* behavior of Xlib, not an unavoidable one, it should not be overly surprising that XCB does things differently, because ....

> Does the XCB
> uses Xlib under the hood, or does it sends commands to the X server in
> some other format?

No, XCB does not use Xlib.  It is an *alternative* to Xlib, a younger sibling written with wisdom that came from experience with Xlib.  Both Xlib and XCB communicate with the X server via the X protocol.<sup>*</sup> They are both low-level, but XCB is more or less a straight protocol wrapper, whereas Xlib presents an API facade hiding X's client / server nature.

And that difference in orientation presents a plausible explanation for the difference in default behavior with respect to window-close buttons.  Xlib tries to guess what the programmer of a GUI application is most likely to want, and it chooses defaults based on that.  Most X applications present a single top-level window, where closing the window terminates the application, and closing the X connection automatically is a convenience for such applications.  XCB, on the other hand, doesn't attempt to hide the X protocol or to layer on policy (though toolkits built on top of it may do).  XCB is all about being transparent about what it does.

> Excuse me, I am not so familiar, how to communicate
> to X11 protocol.

Generally speaking, you communicate by using Xlib or XCB.  It is possible in principle to speak raw X11 to an X server -- after all, that's what Xlib and XCB do -- but doing so is complicated.  That's why Xlib and XCB exist.  And even those are not so easy to use, which is why they have higher-level toolkits built on top of them.

> And in particular, how it come, that window manager
> does not close the connection with XCB?

XCB does not instruct the window manager to do so (at least, not by default).  Xlib doesn't do so either, if you tell it not to do.

---

<sup>*</sup> Or so it was initially.  As one commenter observed, these days, Xlib does not speak the X protocol directly, but rather uses XCB (as opposed to the other way around).

Comment: I think that my use case do not belong to what Xlib thinks a normal GUI program should do. And my application problems does not relate to close button, that you mention. It is as simple as it is stated - multiple windows. And Xlib closes connection as soon as any of them are closed. I do not think I've overlooked anything here. It is just that my principle of least surprise does not converge with the Xlib's.

Comment: And there will be, also, multiple threads. And I smell that I will have a problems with Xlib there too. BTW, if you be so kind, how to "tell Xlib" to change behaviour about closing a connection? I have already some code in Xlib, and maybe, I can manage to do my own syncing of threads, if I will overcome the Xlib habit of closing connections.

Comment: @yww, read the highest voted answer to this question that you already linked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792361/how-do-i-gracefully-exit-an-x11-event-loop, in full (not the accepted one, which isn't nearly as good or relevant).

Comment: With respect to multiple threads making calls to Xlib, do also be sure to use [XInitThreads](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/man/man3/XInitThreads.3.html).

Comment: Modern versions of Xlib in fact use xcb to manage the connection to the X server, since the libX11 1.4.0 release in 2010: https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/xorg-announce/2010-November/001548.html